# I see "Contribution Amounts" in my invoice and Contribution Reports

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page

I see "Contribution Amounts" in my invoice and the Contribution Reports whereas I dont see it added either in Price Set or in the Contribution Page Amount Section.
I am unsure from where its coming from?How can I debug?
Below is the screenshot which has "Contribution Amount" listed
[image]

Comment: Can you replicate the same scenario on dmaster?

Comment: what is dmaster? @PradeepNayak

Comment: dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: can you explain where you got your screenshot from ie what path

Comment: Hi @petednz-fuzion , it was from dev site , I am working on,I added Extended Reports extension , can that be the cause? I will try to disable and see if that fixes it.